# cannot deploy to docker - failing on cryptography and Can not find Rust compiler

Tags: docker, deployment, rust, cryptography

I am trying to deploy a new version on docker but I have an error that I have not seen before. I followed steps to install cryptography and upgrade pip but this did not work. PLEASE let me know if anyone has an idea on how to fix this. THANK YOU!

```
   error: Can not find Rust compiler
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-9vs5iiqi/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-q8luryeh/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-9vs5iiqi/cryptography/

  error: Can not find Rust compiler
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cryptography
  Running setup.py clean for cryptography
Successfully built browser-cookie3 docopt pysftp pyhive pysocks pyyaml s3fs maxminddb pyaes pbkdf2 future sasl thrift thrift-sasl
Failed to build cryptography
```

the requirements I am trying to install are:

```
boto3==1.10.12
browser-cookie3==0.6.4
docopt==0.6.2
requests==2.18.4
pandas==0.23.4
pysftp==0.2.9
pyhive[presto,hive]==0.5.1
pysocks==1.6.8
python-dateutil==2.6.1
flask==0.12.2
awscli==1.15.12
pyyaml==3.12
dask[dataframe]==0.18.2
s3fs==0.1.6
numpy==1.14.3
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
lxml==4.2.1
maxminddb==1.4.1
XlsxWriter==1.2.2
APScheduler==3.6.3
```

Comment: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html#rust

Comment: thank you - i have already followed all those steps but still didnt work @kmdreko

Answer (score 6):

i solved this myself by using
cryptography==3.3.2 in my requirements